# how to convert string object into time object in python 2.4

Tags: python, string, python-datetime

I have two string objects:

```
dt1[1]="00:58:00"    
dt2[1]="01:02:00"
```

If I do,

```
FMT='%H:%M:%S'
SD=datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(dt1[1], FMT)[:6])
FD=datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(dt2[1], FMT)[:6])
```

it translates to `1900-01-01 00:58:00` and `1900-01-01 01:02:00` but I want only the time part not the date.

I have converted date into string and subtracted only the time part from it.
Now i need to convert them to time object again and do `dt2[1]-dt[1]` to find the time difference.

How can I do it.

Answer (score 2):

To get `datetime.time()` objects, just call the [`datetime.datetime.time()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) on the result:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> dt1 = '00:58:00'
>>> dt2 = '01:02:00'
>>> FMT='%H:%M:%S'
>>> datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(dt1, FMT)[:6])
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 58)
>>> datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(dt1, FMT)[:6]).time()
datetime.time(0, 58)
>>> datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(dt2, FMT)[:6]).time()
datetime.time(1, 2)
```

However, if you are going to *subtract* these, use the `datetime.datetime()` objects! You cannot subtract `datetime.time()` objects:

```
>>> res1 = datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(dt1, FMT)[:6])
>>> res2 = datetime.datetime(*time.strptime(dt2, FMT)[:6])
>>> res2.time() - res1.time()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
>>> res2 - res1
datetime.timedelta(0, 240)
```

Comment: I need to subtract only time part. If I subtract date object it will give me 1 day something the original objects are having dates like this :    03-APR-2014 00:58    02-APR-2014 01:02 so if i subtract it, it will show 23 hr something, but i only need to subtract hour and minute part like 01:02 - 00:58 and it will give me 4 mins.

Comment: @Debayan: I know, but if you need to subtract the times, you need *datetime* objects. It doesn't matter for your usecase that the dates an those objects are useless; only that they are the same date.

Comment: I can even convert them entirely to minutes and subtract it.

Comment: @Debayan: sure, but that'd require a different method of parsing; the `time` and `datetime` modules don't deal in durations but in fixed points in time (date, or date + time or time of day) instead.

Comment: So any idea how to find the time difference

Comment: @Debayan: I showed you in my answer, just subtract the `datetime` objects. Because you only parsed a time, they both default to a 1900/01/01 date, and subtracting these two means you are only calculating the difference between the timestamps.

Comment: @Debayan: If you had `datetime.time()` objects only, I'd tell you to build `datetime.datetime()` objects (by using `datetime.datetime.combine()` with `datetime.date.min`) anyway.